# Pandas Standard Deviation returns NaN

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, group-by

I have the following Pandas Dataframe in Python 2.7.

**CODE:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,6),columns=list('ABCDEF'))
df.insert(0,'Category',['A','C','D','D','B','E','F','F','G','H'])
print df.groupby('Category').std()
```

Here is `df`:

```
Category         A         B         C         D         E         F
       A  0.500200  0.791039  0.498083  0.360320  0.965992  0.537068
       C  0.295330  0.638823  0.133570  0.272600  0.647285  0.737942
       D  0.912966  0.051288  0.055766  0.906490  0.078384  0.928538
       D  0.416582  0.441684  0.605967  0.516580  0.458814  0.823692
       B  0.714371  0.636975  0.153347  0.936872  0.000649  0.692558
       E  0.639271  0.486151  0.860172  0.870838  0.831571  0.404813
       F  0.375279  0.555228  0.020599  0.120947  0.896505  0.424233
       F  0.952112  0.299520  0.150623  0.341139  0.186734  0.807519
       G  0.384157  0.858391  0.278563  0.677627  0.998458  0.829019
       H  0.109465  0.085861  0.440557  0.925500  0.767791  0.626924
```

I am looking to perform a `GROUP_BY` and then calculate the average and standard deviation. The standard deviation is *sometimes* calculated after grouping over 1 row - this means dividing by `N-1` will *sometimes* give division by `0` which will print `NaN`.

Here is the output of the above code:

**OUTPUT:**

```
                A         B         C         D         E         F
Category                                                            
A              NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
B              NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
C              NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
D         0.350996  0.276052  0.389051  0.275708  0.269004  0.074137
E              NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
F         0.407882  0.180813  0.091941  0.155699  0.501884  0.271025
G              NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
H              NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

For the cases where I am performing the `GROUP_BY` over 1 row, is there a way to skip the Standard Deviation and just return the value itself. For example, I am looking to get this:

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
                 A         B         C         D         E         F
Category                                                            
A         0.500200  0.791039  0.498083  0.360320  0.965992  0.537068
B         0.714371  0.636975  0.153347  0.936872  0.000649  0.692558
C         0.295330  0.638823  0.133570  0.272600  0.647285  0.737942
D         0.350996  0.276052  0.389051  0.275708  0.269004  0.074137
E         0.639271  0.486151  0.860172  0.870838  0.831571  0.404813
F         0.407882  0.180813  0.091941  0.155699  0.501884  0.271025
G         0.384157  0.858391  0.278563  0.677627  0.998458  0.829019
H         0.109465  0.085861  0.440557  0.925500  0.767791  0.626924
```

Is it possible to do this with Pandas?

EDIT:
To create the exact Pandas Dataframe above, select it, copy to clipboard and then use this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard(index_col='Category')
print df
print df.groupby('Category').std()
```

Comment: How did you calculate the values for Categories D & F in your desired output (e.g. 0.403709 for Category D, column A)?

Comment: Note that `df.groupby('Category').apply(np.std)` returns the std as `0.0`, as you might expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could `fillna` to replace the missing values - passing in a `DataFrame` with the last value of each group.

```
In [86]: (df.groupby('Category').std()
    ...:    .fillna(df.groupby('Category').last()))

Out[86]: 
                 A         B         C         D         E         F
Category                                                            
A         0.500200  0.791039  0.498083  0.360320  0.965992  0.537068
B         0.714371  0.636975  0.153347  0.936872  0.000649  0.692558
C         0.295330  0.638823  0.133570  0.272600  0.647285  0.737942
D         0.350996  0.276052  0.389051  0.275708  0.269005  0.074137
E         0.639271  0.486151  0.860172  0.870838  0.831571  0.404813
F         0.407883  0.180813  0.091941  0.155699  0.501884  0.271024
G         0.384157  0.858391  0.278563  0.677627  0.998458  0.829019
H         0.109465  0.085861  0.440557  0.925500  0.767791  0.626924
```

Answer (score 24):

Not exactly what was asked in the question, but if you wanted to avoid `NaN` values, calculate the *population standard deviation*, specified with `std(ddof=0)`:

```
>>> print(df.groupby('Category').std(ddof=0))
                 A         B         C         D         E         F
Category                                                            
A         0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
B         0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
C         0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
D         0.248192  0.195198  0.275101  0.194955  0.190215  0.052423
E         0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
F         0.288417  0.127854  0.065012  0.110096  0.354885  0.191643
G         0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
H         0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
```

---

Note the different defaults for `ddof` (Delta Degrees of Freedom):

- Pandas: [`DataFrame.std`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.std.html) has default `ddof=1` for *sample standard deviation* (divisor: *N* − 1)
- NumPy: [`numpy.std`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) has default `ddof=0` for *population standard deviation* (divisor: *N*)