# Five questions associated with pandas dataframe groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have **five questions** associated with dataframe groupby:

1. as shown on line 20, why min, max can work w/o quote, but the other functions can only work with quote?
2. are these functions below to `pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy`, `pandas.core.groupby.dataframegroupby`, buitlins or numpy?
3. my answer to question II is that they belong to `pandas.core.groupby.dataframegroupby`, but then what are functions defined for `pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy`, when/how it is used, as some of its functions have the same name as those defined in `pandas.core.groupby.dataframegroupby`, like count, what are the difference between these two classes?
4. see the output for line 22 and 28 for `np.std`, while `np.std(10)` returns 0, but it returns NaN when being invoked in agg for single row with Ticker "mmm"?
5. see line 32 to 36, assume these functions used in agg belong to `pandas.core.groupby.dataframegroupby`, we can also specifically use their corresponding ones defined in numpy module, which is better practice?

My **environment** is: python==3.6.8, pandas==1.1.5, numpy==1.19.4

```
  1 import pandas as pd
  2 import time
  3 from io import StringIO
  4 import warnings
  5 warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
  6
  7 text = """Date   Ticker        Open        High         Low   Adj_Close   Volume
  8     2015-04-09  vws.co  315.000000  316.100000  312.500000  311.520000  1686800
  9     2015-04-10  vws.co  317.000000  319.700000  316.400000  312.700000  1396500
 10     2015-04-13  vws.co  317.900000  321.500000  315.200000  315.850000  1564500
 11     2015-04-14  vws.co  320.000000  322.400000  318.700000  314.870000  1370600
 12     2015-04-15  vws.co  320.000000  321.500000  319.200000  316.150000   945000
 13     2015-04-16  vws.co  319.000000  320.200000  310.400000  307.870000  2236100
 14     2015-04-17  vws.co  309.900000  310.000000  302.500000  299.100000  2711900
 15     2015-04-20  vws.co  303.000000  312.000000  303.000000  306.490000  1629700
 16     2015-04-09     mmm  166.750000  167.500000  166.500000  166.630005  1762800"""
 17
 18 df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), delim_whitespace=1, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0)
 19
 20 df.groupby("Ticker")["Open", "High"].agg([min, max, "count", "mean", "std", "first", "unique"])
 21
 22 df.groupby("Ticker")["Open", "High"].agg("std"), df.groupby("Ticker")["Open", "High"].agg(np.std)
 23 # **OUTPUT**:
 24 # Ticker
 25 # mmm         NaN       NaN
 26 # vws.co  5.95237  4.707972
 27
 28 np.std(10)
 29 # **OUTPUT**:
 30 # 0.0
 31
 32 df.groupby("Ticker")["Open", "High"].agg("min"), df.groupby("Ticker")["Open", "High"].agg(np.min)
 33 df.groupby("Ticker")["Open", "High"].agg("max"), df.groupby("Ticker")["Open", "High"].agg(np.min)
 34 df.groupby("Ticker")["Open", "High"].agg("mean"), df.groupby("Ticker")["Open", "High"].agg(np.mean)
 35 df.groupby("Ticker")["Open", "High"].agg("std"), df.groupby("Ticker")["Open", "High"].agg(np.std)
 36 df.groupby("Ticker")["Open", "High"].agg("cumsum"), df.groupby("Ticker")["Open", "High"].agg(np.cumsum)
```

Comment: The Stackoverflow format prefers *one* question per question, not five. So that it is clear what is asked (and search results lead to one particular issue), and what is answered.

Comment: Questions 1-3 seem closely related, and could be asked as one (IMO).  Question 4 is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49507895/10495893).  Question 5 could be a separate question (might get closed as opinion-based, but perhaps there really is a clear best practice...).

Comment: Thanks Ben, I totally agree with you that 1-3 are closely related. Not sure the given link answer question 4, as it explains the ddof difference between DataFrame.std and nump.std, but in my code, both places are explicitly coded with numpy.std (line 22). Yes, question 5 is opinion, I added it last as I want to hear from your onion. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ben, I think the quoted format are from pandas, while unquoted max/min are from builtins, as all others are not available in builtins, thus they only work with quote. It is just my guess, as not sure how to prove, still partial answer to 1-3.

Comment: [What are all Python Pandas .agg functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53943319/what-are-all-python-pandas-agg-functions) might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you Ynjxsjmh ! your link really help most of these questions,